# Node.js + Socket.io + Express.js Install Errors

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, express, socket.io

I'm trying to have a go at `socket.io` and trying a simple chat example.

So far, here's what I've done:

1. Installed `node.js` (node-v0.12.7-x64 installer)
2. Installed `python2.7` (python-2.7.amd64 installer)
3. Installed `express.js` (npm install express --save)

Now whenever I try `npm install socket.io`, I get error messages that I have no idea how to fix. Can anyone help me please? I just want to try to create a very simple chat to learn `socket.io` for future web projects.

Here's the error messages:

```
$ npm install socket.io
\

> bufferutil@1.1.0 install c:\program files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules
\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild

c:\program files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\eng
ine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gy
p (node "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_m
odules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
c:\program files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\en
gine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj(20,3):
 error MSB4019: The imported project "c:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not f
ound. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that th
e file exists on disk.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074
:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd c:\program files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socket.io\nod
e_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok

> utf-8-validate@1.1.0 install c:\program files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mod
ules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validat
e
> node-gyp rebuild

c:\program files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\eng
ine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_nod
e_gyp (node "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\no
de_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
c:\program files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\en
gine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj(20
,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "c:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was n
ot found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and tha
t the file exists on disk.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074
:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd c:\program files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socket.io\nod
e_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.1.0

> utf-8-validate@1.1.0 install c:\program files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mod
ules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_
modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild

c:\program files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\soc
ket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-v
alidate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_m
odules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuil
d )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
c:\program files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\so
cket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8
-validate\build\validation.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "
c:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Im
port> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074
:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd c:\program files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socket.io\nod
e_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_mo
dules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.1.0

> bufferutil@1.1.0 install c:\program files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules
\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modu
les\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild

c:\program files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\soc
ket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferu
til>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modul
es\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
 else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
c:\program files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\so
cket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\buffe
rutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "c:\M
icrosoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import
> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074
:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd c:\program files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socket.io\nod
e_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_mo
dules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.1.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.1.0
socket.io@1.3.6 node_modules\socket.io
+-- has-binary-data@0.1.3 (isarray@0.0.1)
+-- debug@2.1.0 (ms@0.6.2)
+-- socket.io-parser@2.2.4 (isarray@0.0.1, debug@0.7.4, component-emitter@1.1.2,
 benchmark@1.0.0, json3@3.2.6)
+-- socket.io-adapter@0.3.1 (object-keys@1.0.1, debug@1.0.2, socket.io-parser@2.
2.2)
+-- engine.io@1.5.2 (base64id@0.1.0, debug@1.0.3, engine.io-parser@1.2.1, ws@0.7
.2)
+-- socket.io-client@1.3.6 (indexof@0.0.1, component-bind@1.0.0, to-array@0.1.3,
 debug@0.7.4, backo2@1.0.2, component-emitter@1.1.2, object-component@0.0.3, has
-binary@0.1.6, parseuri@0.0.2, engine.io-client@1.5.2)
```

Comment: It appears as though it's looking for a .NET/C++ installation on your machine that you don't have.

Comment: @JonathanChan here's a screenshot from the Control Panel: http://i.imgur.com/CsNPgGN.png

Comment: Try installing Visual Studio Express edition, if you haven't done it already.

Comment: @praetoriaen I've done that too but I still get these errors. However, I tried to run the application and guess what, it runs smoothly.